# JLStickerview set the background transparent render in UIView using CGContext?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have developed the application using JLStickerview i want to set the background color of UIView with transparent background.

The code is below:

```
public func renderTextOnView(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)

    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)


    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: view.backgroundColor = .clear

Comment: thanks @Damon for you're answere but still not working

Comment: @IrwanMadness Could you please send a link to the library you used?